# How to animate characters from a string in UIView for iPhone app

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone development. Can someone help me with animating characters from an NSArray? I would like to animate and display the characteers in a UIView.

Please help me. Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 0):

add them to a UILabel and use an animation block like:

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animations" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:.3f];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.34f];

    label.frame = CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x, label.frame.origin.y - 20.f, label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```